# Stop triggers from firing on timed import

Tags: trigger, integration

I am currently working on an integration into Salesforce where we need to poll an external database and push a bunch of data into and out of SF. Its mostly gone smoothly, but I need to disable our triggers when doing an import into SF. My concern is that if the polling frequency is every minute and if I simply disable the triggers via a custom setting, then data updates in Salesforce that require the triggers to validate etc may not be fired, causing our data to be invalid. Is there a best way to handle this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we disable triggers, Validation Rules and workflow rules in salesforce org. \[on off - switch\]](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/how-can-we-disable-triggers-validation-rules-and-workflow-rules-in-salesforce-o), pls also see similar one on Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479711/how-can-i-prevent-users-from-editing-the-opportunitylineitem-records-in-salesfor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your triggers to make an exception to the rules based either upon username, role, or something else, like a special hidden field that you only change the value of during imports.

Most orgs I've worked with use a separate dedicated user account for API integrations, so they write their validation rules and triggers to build in the behavior that should apply to that privileged user.

Comment: Great I figured it would be something along these lines. Cheers!