# How do I disable a trigger condition in a class?

Tags: trigger

I am trying to load a raw data to check the functionality of my workflow.It is firing trigger errors.where do I turn off these triggers

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we disable triggers, Validation Rules and workflow rules in salesforce org. \[on off - switch\]](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/how-can-we-disable-triggers-validation-rules-and-workflow-rules-in-salesforce-o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a static flag to enable/disable the execution of your trigger.

Class to hold your flag:

```
class TriggerUtils {
    public static Boolean EnableTriggers = true;
}
```

The trigger:

```
trigger MyTrigger on MyObject__c (...) {
    if (TriggerUtils.EnableTriggers) {
        // Trigger logic
    }
}
```

The code to load data:

```
...
TriggerUtils.EnableTriggers = false;
insert myData; // your DML operation
TriggerUtils.EnableTriggers = true; //optional, you can restore the variable
...
```

This would be a quick solution. Also you could use a Custom Setting to keep the flag if you want to enable and disable the triggers from persisted data.

Hope it helps.